# C# - Converting data from Decimal to float is truncating after decimal points while retrieving data from database

Tags: c#, sql-server, floating-point, decimal

I am trying to fetch percentage value from database and my database query gives 2 digits after decimal, but when i am trying to access that value in c# code, the decimal point and the 2 digits after the decimal points are getting truncated in c#

sample sql statement which i use.

```
Select CAST(COUNT([UserId])*100.0/20 OVER(), 0) from Table AS DECIMAL(10,2)) as [Percentage]
```

The statement returns value like 23.25, 56.12

How do i retain the decimal point and the 2 digits after decimal point ?

Comment: 1. why `Percentage` property is `float` not `decimal` 2. how you know that it is truncated? 3. [it is working fine](https://dotnetfiddle.net/GN8ZLz)

Comment: when i am trying to read the value from employeeObj.Percentage i dont see any decimal point and the digits after decimal

Comment: and why there should be any ? .. UserId seems like integer ... 100/20 is 5 ... if you  multiply 5 by any integer there would be no decimal places

Comment: Divide by 20.0 instead of 20

Comment: @jdweng this is not the problem bcase there is 100.0

Comment: @Selvin : 100.0 is in the numerator and not the denominator.

Comment: and? [on MSSQL aka sql-server it will works](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!18/9eecb/106022)

Comment: @Tarantino I'm afraid you haven't made it very easy for us to help you here: your parentheses don't match, 'OVER()' throws an exception if used as shown, it's not clear what that ', 0' is there for, and AS DECIMAL(10, 2) is after the table name, which is incorrect syntax for the CAST as far as I can see.  Perhaps you can paste the actual SQL that's causing a problem, and show how you are calling it in C# that leads to it truncating?

Comment: In any case, CAST..AS DECIMAL(10,2) does work here.  To show it I created a table 'Test' with a column 'UserId', and put 9 users in it. Then in C# I created a SqlCommand with string `Select CAST(COUNT([UserId])*100.0/20 AS DECIMAL(10,2)) from [Test]`, and did `var result = command.ExecuteScalar();'.  As expected the result is a C# decimal with value 45.00.